# Yocto bitbake Failed Tasks do_fetch Intel Galileo BSP

Tags: intel, yocto, bitbake, intel-galileo, bsp

trying to get the Yocto part of the Galileo BSP going
it does

> source ./iot-devkit-init-build-env yocto_build

but then I run bitbake

> bitbake image-full

it comes back with 33 failed tasks

> Summary: 33 tasks failed:
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-support/sqlite/sqlite3_3.8.3.1.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-extended/bzip2/bzip2_1.0.6.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.61.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-kernel/cryptodev/cryptodev-linux_1.6.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-core/eglibc/eglibc-initial_2.19.bb, do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/elfutils/elfutils_0.155.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-extended/xz/xz_5.1.3alpha.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-support/mpfr/mpfr_3.1.2.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-core/zlib/zlib_1.2.8.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-support/libmpc/libmpc_1.0.2.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/kconfig-frontends/kconfig-frontends_3.12.0.0.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-extended/pigz/pigz_2.3.1.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/file/file_5.16.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl/openssl_1.0.1g.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_20120814.bb, do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-support/gmp/gmp_5.1.1.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_0.28.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_1.5.1.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/flex/flex_2.5.38.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-cross_2.24.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-extended/gperf/gperf_3.0.4.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses_5.9.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.17.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.14.bb, do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/autoconf/autoconf_2.69.bb, do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-core/gettext/gettext_0.18.3.2.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/libtool/libtool-native_2.4.2.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/bison/bison_2.7.1.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-kernel/linux-libc-headers/linux-libc-headers_3.14.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   virtual:native:/home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-support/attr/attr_2.4.47.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-core/eglibc/eglibc_2.19.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/libtool/libtool-cross_2.4.2.bb,
>   do_fetch
>   /home/mark/meta-clanton_v1.1.0-dirty/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross-initial_4.8.bb,
>   do_fetch Summary: There were 34 WARNING messages shown. Summary: There
>   were 66 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

any ideas?

Comment: you can debug using `bitbake -D  image-full` to get verbose messages. are doing fresh build ? Or have u built it successfully ever and getting error now ?

Comment: never built is successfully, first time doing a BSP and im to get it going on an old CentOS

Comment: any help with debug option ? as you posting this on stackoverflow i am assuming your PC is connected to internet :)

Comment: no didnt help.

im behind a proxy but i have http https git all set up .

is there a specific one for fetch?

Comment: I don't think so, i would get the git repository location of one of them and try to clone it in some folder to see if that is working or not.

Comment: the files are there to be downloaded, i have checked that

Comment: Did you add this these packages  OR they are part of original Galileo BSP ? I haven't used yocto for Galileo but i have used it for beaglebone. :(

Comment: they are part of the original im just following a guide

Comment: Is your issue sorted? Otherwise, can you post the fetch log for a couple of the recipes whose fetch task is failing?

Comment: sorry long gone im afraid

yocto didnt like centOS

booted Fedora 20 and everything went smooth